# How can I get MicrosoftDateFormat in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, json, json.net

There is an existing iOS app written in C# that uses MicrosoftDateFormat and `Newtonsoft.Json`.

Sample code :

```
        using Newtonsoft.Json;

        JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
        };
        DateTime current = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(current, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Prints

```
"\/Date(1526376504370)\/"
```

Now I am re writing the app in native objective C. I am getting current date as-

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"Current date %@", now);
```

And this prints

```
Current date Tue May 15 15:02:05 2018
```

How do I convert this into above format? Thanks.

Comment: you mean timestamp?

Comment: Isn't 1526376504370 just the "unix epoch"-based timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date is using the Unix epoch format, you can use [this](https://www.epochconverter.com) converter to test the numbers.

You can use the [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970) property to get the number of seconds and then drop that into the string `/Date(xxxxxxxx)/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get that string then maybe this would help :-

```
NSString *dateString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%ld)/",(long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are correct but very important point to note is that [`timeIntervalSince1970`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdate/1407504-timeintervalsince1970) gives you the number of seconds where as `Newtonsoft.Json` library gives it in milliseconds so you need to do -

```
NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%lld)/",(long long)([currentTag.firstSeenTime timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0)];
```